# A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `filters.startDate` (redux-toolkit.esm.js )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building a budget App using React 18 and Redux
I don't know what is the problem here

```js
import moment from "moment";

const filtersDefaultState = {
  text: "",
  sortBy: "date",
  startDate: moment().startOf("month"),
  endDate: moment().endOf("month"),
};
```

I got this problem after adding moment

```
redux-toolkit.esm.js?8bb3:444 A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path
```

[image: Error Image]

Source code on Github: https://github.com/KhaledGharib/budgetApp

Trying to use DateRangePicker from react-dates

Comment: The problem is that `moment.startOf(..)` and `moment.endOf(..)` return `moment` objects, you'll need to use something like `moment.startOf(..).toDate()` or `moment.startOf(..).format()` (the first one will get you a `Date` object the second one a `String`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `moment.js` date objects are not JSON serializable.

You can "serialize", e.g. stringify, the data yourself:

```js
import moment from "moment";

const filtersDefaultState = {
  text: "",
  sortBy: "date",
  startDate: moment().startOf("month").toISOString(true), // "2023-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  endDate: moment().endOf("month").toISOString(true),     // "2023-03-31T23:59:59.999Z"
};
```

You can alternatively decide to exclude this part of state in the serializability check if you *really* want to store non-serializable objects in the redux store via the [serializabilityMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware):

```js
import { configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import expensesReducer from "../reducers/expenses";
import filtersReducer from "../reducers/filters";

const defaultMiddlewareConfig = {
  serializableCheck: {
    ignoredPaths: ["filters.startDate", "filters.endDate"],
  }
};

export default () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      expenses: expensesReducer,
      filters: filtersReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware(defaultMiddlewareConfig),
  });
  return store;
};
```

Comment: the code works fine when I add the changes but I still get the same error message when I choose the date from DateRangePicker.
looks like this:

A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `startDate`. Value: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Mar 01 2023 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), …} 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {type: 'setStartDate', startDate: Moment}

Comment: @XED My guess here is that you are dispatching a `momentjs` datetime object to the store, saving it directly into state; this too also should be stringified. You can recreate `momentjs` datetime objects when selecting state back to the UI. Does this make sense?

Comment: please take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726410/erorr-a-non-serializable-value-was-detected-in-the-state-in-the-path-filters) I repost all the errors. I hope this provides enough code to understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your `startDate` and `endDate` by adding `toISOString()` function to it or if you are using redux-toolkit, simply set `nonSerializableCheck` to `false`.

```
 const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({serializableCheck:false}).concat(yourCustomMiddleWare),
  });
```