# Erorr: A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `filters.startDate` (redux-toolkit.esm.js )

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-daterange-picker

I'm getting an error here when I add a moment

```
import moment from "moment";

const filtersDefaultState = {
 text: "",
 sortBy: "date",
 startDate: moment().startOf("month"),
 endDate: moment().endOf("month"),
};
```

so I solve this by adding defaultMiddlewareConfig to my configurestore.js file

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import expensesReducer from "../reducers/expenses";
import filtersReducer from "../reducers/filters";

const defaultMiddlewareConfig = {
  serializableCheck: {
    ignoredPaths: ["filters.startDate", "filters.endDate"],
  }
};

export default () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      expenses: expensesReducer,
      filters: filtersReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware(defaultMiddlewareConfig),
  });
  return store;
};
```

after that, the code works fine until using DateRangePicker returns an error
**react_devtools_backend.js:2655 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `startDate`. Value** and **A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `endDate`. Value**

also if I added toISOString(true) to moment it's retruns an error

```
import moment from "moment";

const filtersDefaultState = {
  text: "",
  sortBy: "date",
  startDate: moment().startOf("month").toISOString(true),
  endDate: moment().endOf("month").toISOString(true),
};
```

**Uncaught TypeError: startDate.isSameOrBefore is not a function** and
**Uncaught TypeError: endDate.isSameOrAfter is not a function**

```
import moment from "moment";

export default (expenses, { text, sortBy, startDate, endDate }) => {
  return expenses
    .filter((expense) => {
      const creadtedAtMoment = moment(expense.creadtedAt);

      const startDateMatch = startDate
        ? startDate.isSameOrBefore(creadtedAtMoment, "day")
        : true;

      const endDateMatch = endDate
        ? endDate.isSameOrAfter(creadtedAtMoment, "day")
        : true;
      const textMatch = expense.description
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(text.toLowerCase());

      return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch;
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (sortBy === "date") {
        return a.createdAt < b.createdAt ? 1 : -1;
      } else if (sortBy === "amount") {
        return a.amount < b.amount ? 1 : -1;
      }
    });
};
```

in this file I'm using DateRangePicker

```
import React from "react";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  setEndDate,
  setStartDate,
  setTextFilter,
  sortByAmount,
  sortByDate,
} from "../actions/filters";

class ExpenseListfilters extends React.Component {
  state = {
    calenderFocuesd: null,
  };
  onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    this.props.dispatch(setStartDate(startDate));
    this.props.dispatch(setEndDate(endDate));
  };
  onFocusChange = (calenderFocuesd) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ calenderFocuesd }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          text="text"
          value={this.props.filters.text}
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.props.dispatch(setTextFilter(e.target.value));
          }}
        />
        <select
          value={this.props.filters.sortBy}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === "date") {
              this.props.dispatch(sortByDate());
            } else if (e.target.value) {
              this.props.dispatch(sortByAmount());
            }
          }}
        >
          <option value="date">Date</option>
          <option value="amount">Amount</option>
        </select>
        <DateRangePicker
          startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
          endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
          onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
          focusedInput={this.state.calenderFocuesd}
          onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
          showClearDates={true}
          numberOfMonths={1}
          isOutsideRange={() => false}
          startDateId="MyDatePickerStart"
          endDateId="MyDatePickerEnd"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    filters: state.filters,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpenseListfilters);
```

As I mentioned above I tried these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715252/a-non-serializable-value-was-detected-in-the-state-in-the-path-filters-startd) but can't solve other problems

Comment: Source code on Github: https://github.com/KhaledGharib/budgetApp

Answer (score 1):

If you are stringifying the `momentjs` datetime objects to be stored in the store, then they should be converted back to `momentjs` datetime objects for the UI if that's what it needs.

Example:

```js
import moment from "moment";

...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  filters: {
    ...state.filters,
    startDate: moment(state.filters.startDate),
    endDate: moment(state.filters.endDate),
  },
});
```

The change handler will likely also need to again stringify the datetime objects when dispatched to the store.

```js
onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
  this.props.dispatch(setStartDate(startDate.toISOString(true)));
  this.props.dispatch(setEndDate(endDate.toISOString(true)));
};
```

If you like/prefer you can instead do this conversion in the action creators:

```js
onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
  this.props.dispatch(setStartDate(startDate));
  this.props.dispatch(setEndDate(endDate));
};
```

```js
export const setStartDate = (startDate) => ({
  type: "setStartDate",
  startDate: startDate.toISOString(true),
});

export const setEndDate = (endDate) => ({
  type: "setEndDate",
  endDate: endDate.toISOString(true),
});
```