# Serialising date objects in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, redux-toolkit, prisma

I am creating a personal project using NextJS, Prisma, MongoDB and Redux Toolkit and I am getting a few of these errors in my browser console:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `generate.createdImage.createdAt`. Value: Mon Jan 15 2024 17:10:56 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: generate/addGeneratedImage

Having trawled the internet for hours I have almost given up hope, could someone please help!

A form is submitted and a post gets created in the DB, this post has all the usual fields including a “createdAt” date object. Once created this post is then being returned to the frontend, where I am pushing it to my redux state, hence the error.

I have two questions (code to follow):

1. Should I just store the dates as strings in MongoDB? If so how do I query these strings in my server action? (For example get the 5 most recent posts).
2. If I should be using date object, where exactly should I be serialising it? Before it gets returned to the frontend?

Here is my prisma model for the post:

```
model Post {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title         String?
  imageUrl      String
  size          String
  hd            Boolean       
  prompt        String
  revisedPrompt String
  model         String
  author        User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId      String    @db.ObjectId
  tagIDs        String[]   @db.ObjectId
  tags          Tag[] @relation(fields: [tagIDs], references: [id])
  createdAt     DateTime   @default(now())
}
```

Here is my server action:

```
export const createPostPartial = async (imageObject: ImagePartialProps) => {
      const { userId, s3FileURL, imageParams, revisedPrompt } = imageObject;
    
      let post;
    
      try {
        post = await db.post.create({
          data: {
            imageUrl: s3FileURL,
            size: imageParams.size!,
            hd: imageParams.quality === 'hd' ? true : false,
            prompt: imageParams.prompt,
            revisedPrompt: revisedPrompt,
            model: imageParams.model!,
            authorId: userId,
          },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return {
          error: 'Failed to create the post',
        };
      }
    
      return post;
    };
```

Dispatching the action on the FE:

```
dispatch(addGeneratedImage(data.success.createdImage));
```

And finally the slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type GenerateState = {
  createdImage: ImagePostProps;
  pending: boolean;
};
export type ImagePostProps = {
  id: string;
  authorId: string;
  hd: boolean;
  imageUrl: string;
  model: string;
  prompt: string;
  revisedPrompt: string;
  size: string;
  tagIDs: string[];
  title: string | null;
  createdAt: string;
};

const initialState = {
  pending: false,

  createdImage: {
    id: '',
    authorId: '',
    hd: false,
    imageUrl: '',
    model: '',
    prompt: '',
    revisedPrompt: '',
    size: '',
    tagIDs: [],
    title: '',
    createdAt: '',
  } as ImagePostProps,
} as GenerateState;

const generateSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'generate',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    addGeneratedImage: (state, action) => {
      state.createdImage = action.payload;
    },
    switchPending: (state, action) => {
      state.pending = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { addGeneratedImage, switchPending } = generateSlice.actions;
export default generateSlice.reducer;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the "A non-serializable value was detected in…" a message in the backend with the DB, or is this in the frontend with Redux? Please [edit] to include the complete warning message and clarify where this occurs.

Comment: Done! Apologies Drew!

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715252/a-non-serializable-value-was-detected-in-the-state-in-the-path-filters-startd/75717104#75717104 Basic gist is that you can serialize the data yourself in the reducer, and deserialize it when reading back out of state, ***or*** you can configure the serializability middleware. It would appear that you've typed the `createdAt` property to be a string, so you should store a string value. Otherwise, configure the middleware to ignore this state and update the `ImagePostProps` interface to allow `DateTime` objects.

Comment: HI Drew, thanks for responding. I read this earlier but when i do this is in initialState:

`createdAt: new Date().toString(),`

I get the same errors. I am just getting confused on exactly how to serialise the date object coming through.

Comment: I believe it should be `(new Date()).toString()`. You might need to serialize the `createdAt` property in any actions that are dispatched. You might take a combination of both, configuring to ignore specific actions, and serializing into state.

Comment: Cheers Drew will have a crack! Thanks for your time!